# A question on analytic vectors of $p$-adic analytic groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, p-adic-analysis

I have some trouble understanding the proof of the first part of proposition $3.3.23$ of [this famous paper](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~emerton/pdffiles/analytic.pdf) by M.Emerton.  The proposition says that:

Let $G$ be a affinoid rigid analytic  group, $K$ finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
Let $V$ be Hausdorff locally convex $K$-space equipped with a topological $G$-action, and let $W$ be a $G$-invariant closed subspace of $V$. If $W_1$ denotes the preimage of $W$ in $V_{G-an}$ (that is the *globally* $G$-analytic vectors of $V$) under the natural map $V_{G-an} \rightarrow V$. (I believe that $W_1=W \cap V_{G-an}$). Then the map $W_{G-an} \rightarrow V_{G-an}$ induces a continuous bijection of $W_{G-an}$ onto $W_1$.

The author says that this follows from proposition $2.1.23$ and theorem $3.3.16$. But I have trouble understanding it.

First of all, why is it true that 
$$\mathcal{C}(G,W)_{G-an}=\mathcal{C}(G,W) \cap \mathcal{C}(G,V)_{G-an}?$$

Here, $\mathcal{C}(G,W)_{G-an}$ is the space of $G$-globally analytic functions and $\mathcal{C}(G,W)$ is the space of continuous functions.
Further, how does the injections $V_{G-an} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{C}(G,V)_{G-an} $ and $W_{G-an} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{C}(G,W)_{G-an} $ imply that 
$$W_{G-an}=W \cap V_{G-an}?$$

Thanks for explanations and help.